# use if else statement inside apply function in R

Tags: r, if-statement, apply

I have following 2 columns

```
lower=rnorm(10,0,1)
upper=rnorm(10,1,1)

dd=data.frame(lower,upper)
```

i wanted to know whether for each row , lower < 0.5 and upper > 1. I did it using a for loop  as follows,

```
cc=c()
for(i in 1: 10 ){
  cc[i]= ifelse(  (  dd$upper[i] > 1 && dd$lower[i] < 0.5  ),1,0
  )
}
```

But i wanted to do this using one of the suitable apply function. Since the data is in a data frame, i tried using apply function . This is my code,

```
apply(dd , 1, function (i,j) {ifelse( (dd$i> 0.5 && dd$j<0.5) ,0,1 )

}
  )
```

I am getting NA 's. It is really helpful if someone help me figure out the mistake

Thank you

Comment: Please use `set.seed` before generating random data and also update your expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the solution below is much easier compared to what you have tried. Have a look

```
set.seed(10)
lower=rnorm(10,0,1)
upper=rnorm(10,1,1)

dd=data.frame(lower,upper)

dd$flag<-ifelse((dd$lower < 0.5 & dd$upper > 1),1,0)
```

This will give you the required output.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is in defining the inputs to function parameter `FUN` in `apply`. Think of this input as the complete array rather than individual elements of array.

```
set.seed(10)
lower <- rnorm(10,0,1)
upper <- rnorm(10,1,1)
dd <- data.frame(lower,upper)
apply(dd, 1, FUN=function(x){ifelse(x[1] < 0.5 && x[2] > 1, 1, 0)})
[1] 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
```

Alternatively, you can also do

```
apply(dd , 1, FUN = function (x) {ifelse(x["lower"] < 0.5 && x["upper"] > 1, 1, 0)})
```